# Not able to access inner class data from outer class in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code. I am not able to access the username which is in signUp collection. I am getting the value but not accessible from outside.

So please tell me some method to do.

I am also pasting snapshot of my database there are two tables from which I need to access data and display then display in a recycler view. Need to display value in a list format.

I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sflsF.png)

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listItems=new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("post").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                post p=ds.getValue(post.class);
                String user=p.getUid();
              final  String nh,nd;
                nh=p.getNewsHeading();
                nd=p.getNewsDiscription();

                databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                databaseReference.child("signUp").child(user).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        signUp s=dataSnapshot.getValue(signUp.class);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s.getUser(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//want to access username from outside

                        userName =s.getUser();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });

                p=new post(nh,nd,userName);
                listItems.add(p);
            }
            listItems.add(new post("hdfsgidsf","d,hdjh","ramu babu")) ;
            myAdapter adapter;
            adapter=new myAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //******************************************************************************************************

}
```

Comment: ondatachange is an asychronous method

Comment: where is "outside"? You could write a `MyValueEventListener` class that extends `ValueEventListener` but also offers a way to access the latest version of the username. Then use a variable `MyValueEventListener myVEL = new MyValueEventListener(){...}` which you add as listener to your `child("post")` and access the username later with `myVEL.getUsername()` or so.    I am aware this could be an answer, but I want to first verify that this fits your problem

Comment: I am not able to get the approach you are telling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onDataChange()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the Task it returns will be called sometime later.  There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `userName` variable you're trying to use outside the `onDataChange()` method, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to return a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous.  That's not a good idea.  You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solution for this problem would be to use the `userName` string only inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

**Edit:** Feb 26th, 2021

For more info, you can check the following article:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

And the following video:

- https://youtu.be/mOB40wowo6Y